# Notation/definition for the state of a FIFO queue

Tags: lo.logic, notation

A first-in first-out queue is filled up by tokens $t \in T$. The state of the queue  $q \in Q$ is being changed by two operations,
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{push} : Q \times T \rightarrow Q
\end{equation}
which pushes a token to the end of the queue and
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{pop} : Q \rightarrow Q \times T
\end{equation}
which pops a token from the beginning of the queue.
Let's suppose $T = \lbrace 2, 3, 5, 7, 13\rbrace$
Let's suppose $q = [2, 3, 5]$ is the initial token state and a token being pushed to a queue is $t = 3$.
Then
\begin{equation}
  q' = \mathrm{push}(q, t) = [2,3,5,3]
\end{equation}
Suppose that afterwards a token is being popped from the queue.
Then 
\begin{equation}
  (q'', t')  = \mathrm{pop}(q')
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
  &q'' = [3, 5, 3]\\
  &t' = 2
\end{align}
I have a problem saying what the set of queue states $Q$ is.
It is a set of lists which contain the elements from a set $T$.
The closest I get is the abuse of notation of a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), i.e. $Q = \mathcal{P}(T)$.
There exists a [power set of a multi-set](https://oeis.org/wiki/Multisets#Powerset_of_a_multiset) which allows repetition of elements, but it requires a further disclaimer that $T$ is a "proper" set and only its "power set" is a multi-set. Furthermore, the elements of this power set can be repeated unknown number of times.

Can you, please, help me with notation. If you have a reference to an existing work this would be great, but any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It is the Kleene closure of $T$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star .  But this question is not appropriate for this list, hence the downvote.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay is right (except that the system currently shows no downvote).

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thank you! If you copy/paste your first sentence to an answer, I will accept it. This is the answer I was looking for. I have to say I can understand your critique, I wasn't sure where to ask this question, and which tags to assign it. If you think it would be helpful for somebody else to edit the tags, please, do so, or suggest me  how to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be more appropriate on: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I didn't downvote (which I rarely do for questions).  I voted to close.